# how test call back function? VUE/JEST

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I no any idea how test `updateTotal`... if `requestAxios` is success return callback function `updateTotal` but how i spy that?

```
...methods:{

     updateAll() {

          const updateTotal = (request) => {
              this.total = request.data.total
          }

          this.requestAxios(
             'get',
              '/api/',
              {},
              [updateTotal],
          )

       }
}...
```

requestAxios:

```
async requestAxios(
            method = 'get',
            url = '',
            objSend = {},
            successFunctions = [],
            errorsFunctions = [],
            formKey = 'form',
        ) {

        let request = ''

        if (method !== 'delete') {
            request = await axios[method](url, objSend, this.headerRequestJson)
                .then(response => this.responseRequestText(response))
                .catch(errors => this.responseRequestText(errors.response));
        } else {
            request = await axios.delete(url, {
                data: objSend,
                headers: this.headerRequestJson.headers,
            })
                .then(response => this.responseRequestText(response))
                .catch(errors => this.responseRequestText(errors.response));
        }

        if (request.status === 'success') {
            // success callback fn
            successFunctions.forEach((value) => {
                value(request, formKey)
            })
        } else {
            // errors callback fn
            errorsFunctions.forEach((value) => {
                value(request)
            })
            // adicionar erros nos campos
            this.addErrors(request, formKey);
        }
    },
```

My attempt:

```
test('updateTotalFinancial: ', () => {
            const update = jest.fn()
            const response = {
                data: {
                    total: 100,
                },
            }
            const requestAxios = jest.fn(() => update(response))

            const wrapper = shallowMount(ModalUnderwriting, {
                store,
                localVue,
                methods: {
                    requestAxios,
                },

            })
            wrapper.setData({
               total: '0',
            })

            wrapper.vm.updateTotalFinancial()
```

first expect success second not, not update data/variabel `total`

```
expect(update).toBeCalled()
expect(wrapper.vm.total).toEqual(100)
```

Comment: Which part of this are you trying to test? If `updateAll`, mock out `requestAxios` and call the success (and/or error, depending on the scenario) passed to it directly. But that seems like quite an old-fashioned interface, can't you use promises?

Comment: i can test `updateAll`. But how i 'connect' `requestAxios` with `update` ? i guess my thought/logic is going in the wrong direction...  i used async/await (are promisses, no?) sorry, but i'm a noob JS and English :(

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "connect ... with update". What update? And you've used promises (mixing async/await with .then/.catch, which is generally a bad idea) *inside* requestAxios, but why not expose a promise API to its users?

Comment: I dont understand why bad idea asyc/await with then/catch, is it better use try/catch into async function?

Comment: In my opinion it's better *not* to mix and match the two ways of handling promises, at least not in the same function.

Comment: I update post, with my attempt but not work